# how to access the grids on silverlight

Tags: silverlight, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0

I have a button called test button an when I click on it I want to show a grid whose visbility is set to 0

I created a mouse button event (below) but my Grid (testGrid) is not available in the project.

```
private void testButton(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {       
           testGrid.Opacity = 1;                                                                              
        }
```

it highlights testGrid red

new to SL  so not sure whats going on here

** EDIT **

xml for the Grid

```
    <Grid x:Name="testGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="150" Margin="950,-77,0,0" Height="77" VerticalAlignment="Top" Opacity="0">

    </Grid> 



<Image x:Name="testButton" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,1,180,3"  Stretch="Fill" Width="53" Height="49"  Cursor="Hand" Opacity="0.8" >
```

Comment: we need to see the XAML and more of the code would be good too

Comment: I added xaml. I am thinking something like Grid testGrid = FindName("")???

Comment: You shouldn't have to use FindName, that should be done for you in InitializeComponent which should be called in your constructor. You may want to go to the constructor, right click, and go to definition and see if the testGrid declaration is generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:
On  XAML

```
<Grid x:Name="testGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="150" Margin="950,-77,0,0" Height="77" VerticalAlignment="Top" Opacity="0">
</Grid>
<Image x:Name="testButton" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,1,180,3"  Stretch="Fill" Width="53" Height="49"  Cursor="Hand" Opacity="0.8" MouseLeftButtonDown="testButton" />
```

on the cs

```
private void testButton(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e){       
       testGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason that your grid might not be accessibly in the .cs file is if you have changed the class name in the .cs file, but not in the Xaml directive at the top of your .xaml file.

If these two mis match, visual studio won't be able to link up the two files and so you wouldn't be able to see the grid control in the code behind.

Other items with your code to consider:

Though Opacity will work an alternative I use more often is:

This will show the grid.

```
testGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

This will hide the grid.

```
testGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Also, Your "Button" is an Image tag and not a button. It is an image with the same name as the method you are trying to call. You will either need to change your Image to allow for an on click event or change it to a button, something like

```
<Button Click="TestBUtton" Text="MyButton" />
```

And I'd enter that in the Xaml directly so that when you type in the `click` event handler it auto generates the method in the code behind for you.

Comment: While I agree that Visibility is more efficient than Opacity, the question is about the fact that the backing field for testGrid is not being generated and there is a compile time error.

Comment: @Bill fair comment. But I had hoped through changing the button and the link through to the code behind the reason for testGrid not being available may become apparent.

Comment: Fair enough, tried to remove the -1 but it wouldn't let me. I'm now thinking the OP changed the class name and didn't change it in the XAML so the code gen in broken.

Comment: That is more than likely the answer. As that would break the link between Xaml and the code behind. I guess i was just jumping the gun trying to solve the problems also involved rather than the question at hand.

Comment: If you add that suggestion to your answer I think I'll be able to remove the -1

Comment: Edited to reflect the answer ammendment but also tidy up the rest